# Is it important to make a feature scaling before using Gaussian Mixture Model?

Tags: math, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, gaussian

Is it important to make a feature scaling before using Gaussian Mixture Model? and why is it important while we are using probability in getting our clusters's parameters (mean and covariance matrix).
On the other hand, I know that it's important to standardize our data before using K-mean as clustering here depend on the Ecludiane distance between points and the cluster, and if a feature have large values it would dominate this multidimensional distance calculation

Comment: This isn't a programming questions so much as a statistical methodology question. It is thus a much better fit for [statistics.se] than it is for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Gaussian Mixture Modeling you learn the extend and scale of clusters. So scaling this should - ideally - not make any difference. You'll just get differently scaled covariance matrixes afterwards.